# Camunda versioning audit log of process instances

Tags: camunda

I have a requirement where I have to compare and create an audit log of different versions of process instances.

Suppose we have a process with id “loanApproval” which has versions 1 and 2. My requirement is to compare these 2 versions and generate an audit log of changes made between these versions.

for instance, if version 1 was
start → get loan → approve loan → end

and version 2 was

start → get loan → approve loan → notify requester → end

The audit log would have to generate something like “A new service task “notify requester” was added”

Any ideas how to get about this?

Also posted it here: https://forum.camunda.org/t/versioning-audit-log-of-process-instances/26563

Answer (score 1):

I am wondering ... if you need the changes on "a new service task was added" level, you do not need to analyze the runtime behavior, you could do a static comparison between the old bpmn-xml and the new bpmn-xml.

This can be done either by diffing the xml src, using the Bpmn model api or a js/graphical tool like https://demo.bpmn.io/diff.

Comment: Thanks. Can you recommend any tools to diff the XML src or how I can integrate https://demo.bpmn.io/diff with some modifications in my java application

Comment: Sorry, I have nothing just to re-use ... I guess using the java Bpmn model API would be the most "straight forward" approach, read both models and iterate over the elements to collect diffs programmatically.